# Pulsating effect on icon in HTML5 with CSS

Tags: css, html

I have an element

```
<a class="fa fa-user icon" href="#"></a>
```

My requirement is to have a pulsing effect whenever the mouse is on top of it.

My CSS is something like this.

```
.icon:hover{
    -webkit-animation: pulse 2s ease-in;
    -moz-animation: pulse 2s ease-in;
     animation: pulse 2s ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.0;
 }
 25% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.35);
    opacity: 0.1;
 }
 50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.7);
    opacity: 0.3;
 }
 75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.05);
    opacity: 0.5;
 }
 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.4);
    opacity: 0.0;
 }
}
```

The effect works fine but the thing is the original icon disappears. I want the original icon to remain visible while the pulsating effect is happening to make it stand out while the person is holding the mouse on top of it.

Do I need to overlay the original div with a new icon?

JSFiddle is available: https://jsfiddle.net/3bu8fxnp/9/

Comment: Is it what you want? [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/3bu8fxnp/13/).

Comment: No I want the icon to be visible at all times and another layer pulsating around it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/3bu8fxnp/10/)

You can add a second icon in the `after` pseudo element.

```
.fa-user:after {
    content: "\f007";
    display: block;
}

.fa-user:before {
    position: absolute;
}
```

You need to change the selector with the transition as well to only affect one of the pseudo elements.

```
.icon:hover:before {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, may I know what if I have a small Image (not fontawesome icon), what should I do in the before section then?

Comment: I guess you could tweek this solution to work with a background image and scale it to fit the size of the pseudo element.